# Push Notification iOS with Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, notifications, push

I've been looking around and read the documentation on Parse that has been provided by Parse. I've seen that push notifications may require a backend coding implementation such as REST API & Cloud Code.I would like to know is there any possibilities to restrain to any backend coding activities.

I'm building medical social app which an app requires to push notification to a specific user(doctor sends message privately to specific patient).That being said, do I need backend coding activities?

Answer (score 1):

No, you could use Client Push instead.

Something like that:

```
let push = PFPush()
push.setMessage("Hello, test push!")
push.sendPushInBackground()
```

[Link](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications) to documentation.